# how to pass values when opening another window in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
   <input type="text" id="first_one" value="<?php echo $from_date ; ?>"/>
```

Anchor Tag

here i am having an achor tag...on clicking this anchor a function is called....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function newwin() { 
    var a=document.getElementById("first_one").value; 

 myWindow=window.open('try1.php?leadid=a','myWin','width=400,height=650')
 }
         </script>
```

now in this function what i am trying this that whenever i click on anchor tag...it should open another window and take the value of textbox with it....but it is not taking anything...can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myWindow=window.open('try1.php?leadid=' + encodeURIComponent(a),'myWin','width=400,height=650')
```

You were always passing the character `'a'` instead of the actual value of `a`.

Comment: ok  but if i want to pass two values instead of that...so do i need to put AND condition like this .....+a && +b  ??

Comment: No, like this `'a=' + a + '&b=' + b`

Comment: @user3138522: See Adrian's answer for why this answer is incorrect.

Comment: but 'a=' + a + '&b=' + b like this also its working absolutely fine...then y do i need to write encodeURIComponent??

Comment: @user3138522 Type `this & that` into your textbox. You'll find out quickly enough.

Comment: @user3138522 because if you have weird characters in your text, they should be encoded into a URI compliant format, for example if you have the '&' character as Adrian said, it is not going to simply work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myWindow=window.open('try1.php?leadid=' +
                    encodeURIComponent(a),'myWin','width=400,height=650')
```

Your issue is that you are treating 'a' as a value, rather than as a variable, so the literal string "a" was being passed through rather than the variable's value.

The `encodeURIComponent` is used to ensure that the value is made safe to include in URLs.

Comment: I've wrapped it in `encodeURIComponent` to avoid that being an issue.

Comment: I felt it better to explain the actual problem - the 'a' being included in the string instead of referenced as a variable - rather than ensuring an 100% correct solution as a first step. Thanks for the reminder, though.

Comment: You should wait to post until the answer is correct. Suppose you get called away, your 'net goes down, etc.? The questioner is left with misleading information. There's nothing "slightly" incorrect about just dumping `a` on the end without encoding it. It's just wrong. Now the answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation:

```
open('try1.php?leadid=' + a +'
```